# Gnome tweak tool won't start with user themes in gnome-shell

Tags: gnome, themes, gnome-tweak-tool

Can't launch Gnome Tweak Tool when the [User Themes](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) extensions is enabled.

When I tried from terminal, the output was:

```
petr@sova:~$ gnome-tweak-tool 

(gnome-tweak-tool:6475): GLib-GIO-ERROR **: Settings schema 'org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme' is not installed

Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
```

Gnome Tweak Tool works correctly without User Themes.

Ubuntu 12.04, gnome-shell 3.4.1

Relevant (closed) question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/91512/gnome-tweak-tool-doesnt-start

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar question [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1950745)

**Howto:**

Add the official Gnome Shell Extensions ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
```

Install dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-common
```

Afterwards, enabling on the [link provided](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/) works fine.

Comment: That just removes the extension. Don't want that. But the linked forum post solved my issue. Thanks!

Comment: can you elaborate on the "FIX" I will include it in the answer

Comment: @PetrMarek nice

Answer (score 1):

install the gnome shell extension user theme even though it gives error then run the following two commands

```
sudo cp $HOME/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com/schemas/org.gnome.shell.extensions.user-theme.gschema.xml /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

after that reload shell att+f2 then running r

here is the link where i got the solution http://www.fandigital.com/2012/09/fix-user-themes-gnome-shell-extension.html